# Text to Emoji is not working in flutter when String "\u2764" is fetched from firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to convert "\u2764" which is a heart to emoji.

1. Whenever I input or hardcode "\u2764" to text widget then, it automatically converts to heart.

```
Text(
   "\u2764",
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
),
```

1. When ever I fetch same String from firestore then it stays as String only.

```
Text(
   question.getEmoji,
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
),
```

3. If I declare a variable and hardcode its value to "\u2764" then it is also working fine.

But I want to store emoji in my database and fetch values on runtime.

[image: text to emoji issue]

Answer (score 0):

When fetching a string from Firestore, it might be stored as a plain string with escape characters like "\u2764" instead of being automatically converted to the corresponding emoji representation.

**EDIT**

Simply use `json.decode` from `dart:convert` but only if it follows the Unicode sequence format otherwise maybe an other approach is needed

```
String firestoreString = r"\u2764"; // Escaped string fetched from Firestore

// Convert the escape sequence to emoji
String emoji = json.decode('"$firestoreString"');

print(emoji); // Outputs the emoji
```

**INFO**

If the emoji is still not displayed make sure you are using a font that supports emoji.

You can add this in your TextStyle for example: `fontFamily: 'EmojiOne'`

Comment: Not working, Error: type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'int'. 
I changed it to emoji = String.fromCharCode(data['emoji'].runes.toList())

Comment: Hey Rishabh, indeed I thought it would work like that, here is an updated and tested solution ;)